# How to fix (0 KB)file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I open Jupiter-notebook on my ipad,
and go to my files I see the file (0 KB)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qUap.jpg),
and when i open it i see this
“Error loading notebook”

(Unreadable Notebook: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F74A3BC-6A81-4937-A524-AAFF345DF2BB/tmp/NSIRD_Carnets_GeJck5/file_name.ipy)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95BTb.png)

**Please help me, i have 2 projects in this file**

Comment: Have you been able to access it before on your iPad?  What app are you using? (e.g. Juno)?

Comment: Can you open this file in another device? Its size differ?

Answer (score 0):

same thing happen with me my project work file I saved but when I open it in morning it not opening their size become 0kb. showing error “Error loading notebook”   following steps to recover that file that i did and i get that file.

**step 1)** open the file explorer/my computer.
**step 2)** from windows explorer "view tab"  click on show hidden file.
**step 3)** goes to that folder where you stored that jupyter (.ipnb) file.
**step 4)** when show hidden file option enable then you see you jupyter file
but in hidden format you need to rename it by just remove **" . "**
dot from its name and rename it and save.
Ex.file name is  "**.LSTM model**" then rename it by removing dot(.)
before file name and give name " **LSTM model** "
**step 5)**  now this rename file is open from jupyter notebook.

(***Note***: *actully jupyter file backup store in hidden format in windows if we enable show hidden file from window explorer we can rename and reuse file which is corrupted)*